# Activity transition is slow, but method profiling does not show anything abnormal

Tags: android, performance, android-traceview

I have an activity where entering it is time-costly (around 1 second).

I tried using DDMS to track what was happening during activity transition.
I started the track, press the button where it starts the new activity, and then stop the tracking.
However, I cannot find any suspicious method in method profiling.

[image: trace view]

So... to conclude, I may lay out my question this way:

1. Did I use traceview correctly? I always sort by Excl Cpu time to see if any method is taking up the most time. However, in the trace above, the slowest method takes less than 83ms.
2. If you have similar experience (i.e. Activity transition is slow, but you cannot find anything in traceview), how do you end up solving it?

Comment: Can you share your activity? Is it heavy on the layout? Are you querying synchronously on the main thread? Any heavy allocations?

Comment: @toshkinl I try to avoid giving my activity because that would be too much to ask a question. As for your question, I removed the heavy parts of the layout but problem persists; no query on main thread, and no heavy allocations as well. Simply inflating.That's why I try to focus my question on trace view.